# Handle HttpHandler column inside of jquery...how to add field in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-autocomplete

I tried posting this question earlier and I think I made no sense :).  So here is my second attempt.  I have an asp.net project where I use jquery ui autocomplete to display names of employees when you type.  I got that part working fine.  But what I wanted to do is add an image of each employee when the autocomplete results come up.  So that when you type a "J" for instance you see Joe, Jon, etc and next to each name the employees photo.  I store the photo path in the database so this should be no problem I thought.  Here was my httphandler (the .ashx file in .net):

```
 public class LoadNames : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            DataSet ds = null;
            List<Employee> lstEmployees = new List<Employee>();

            ds = GetLoginNames();

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    lstEmployees.Add(new Employee { Name = dr["Login"].ToString(), Picture = dr["Picture"].ToString() });
                }
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (Employee e in lstEmployees)
                {
                    builder.Append(string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", e.Name, e.Picture, Environment.NewLine));
                }
                context.Response.Write(builder.ToString());
            }
        }

        public DataSet GetLoginNames()
        {
            SqlCommand cmdSelect = default(SqlCommand);
            SqlConnection conMyData = default(SqlConnection);
            SqlDataAdapter daIssues = default(SqlDataAdapter);
            System.Data.DataSet ds = null;

            conMyData = null;

            //try and make a connection   
            try
            {
                conMyData = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]);
                cmdSelect = new SqlCommand("selLoginNames", conMyData);

                var _with1 = cmdSelect;
                _with1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //add parameters
                _with1.Parameters.Add("@Inactive", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
                daIssues = new SqlDataAdapter();
                daIssues.SelectCommand = cmdSelect;
                ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                daIssues.Fill(ds);

                return ds;
                //catch any exceptions that might be thrown
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
                //clean up and close resources
            }
            finally
            {
                conMyData.Close();
                cmdSelect = null;
                conMyData = null;
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically this class gets the data and stores it in a list of Employees.  Then I build it using the employees name: `Login` and their Picture, `Picture`.  So I got this part working.  Now on the jquery side I don't know how to modify it to include the picture.  So far all I have is the actual text of their name:

```
$("#<%= txtName.ClientID %>").livequery(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete("LoadNames.ashx", { minChars: 0, delay: 0 })
             .result(function (event, data, formatted) { // data[0] : Login, data[1] :Picture, data[2]:newline character
                 if (data[0] != "") {
                     var url = "http://someURL/Default.aspx?Search=" + data[0];
                     window.open(url);
                 }
                 else {
                 }
             });
            });
```

My question is how do I modify the jquery above to include the picture to be shown in the autocomplete results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        $("#<%= txtName.ClientID %>").livequery(function () {
            $(this).autocomplete("LoadNames.ashx", { minChars: 0, delay: 0, formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
        return "<img src='" + data[1] + "' width='50' height='50'/> " + value.split(".")[0];
    }})
         .result(function (event, data, formatted) { // data[0] : Login, data[1] :Picture, data[2]:newline character
             if (data[0] != "") {
                 var url = "http://someURL/Default.aspx?Search=" + data[0];
                 window.open(url);
             }
             else {
             }
         });
        });
```